# Удалить дублирующий блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок с людьми, но иногда человек дублируется. Как с помощью JS удалить дублирующего человека?
Возможно как-то сделать через `data-id`, у всех id уникален, а у дублирующих одинаковый.

[image: Есть блок с людьми, но иногда человек дублируется. Как с помощью JS удалить дублирующего человека?]

Comment: Возможно. Вам код написать?

Comment: @Igor не обязательно, можно просто идею подсказать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var uniqueIds = {};
$("selector for blocks").each(function(){
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  if (uniqueIds[id]) {
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    uniqueIds[id] = true;
  }
});
```